# Taking values through input and diplaying them during run time

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, input

I need to write a program where during run time, a set of integers of arbitrary size will taken as input. They will be seperated by white space. At the end, a new line is given, showing the end of input. How do I save them into an array of integers so that i can display them later. I think it is a little difficult because the number of values that will be entered is not known during compilation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like homework.

Correct me if I am wrong and I will give you more than hints.

You can either declare an array of a really large size that would not possibly  be filled by the user input, then use scanf  or something like that to grab the integers until you hit '\n', or you can grab each integer at a time, allocating memory as you go, using a combination of malloc and memcpy calls. The first option should never be done in a real world problem, and I am certainly not advocating such practices even though your textbook probably tells you to do it this way.

There is an example just like this in K&R.

This is a typical problem you will have in C. The solution is usually one of two options.

1. Use a really large array that is large enough to hold the input. Sometimes this is a poor option when the data could be really large. An example of when it would be a bad idea is when you are saving a video frame or a large text file to the array. This also opens you up to a buffer overrun attack in older versions of Windows. However, this is sometimes a good quick hack solution for smaller (homework) programs where you can count on the user (i.e. your professor who is not trying to break your program) to not input 1000's of characters. Usually this is considered bad practice, please consider my 2nd option for the security reason I mentioned before.
2. Use dynamic arrays (i.e. malloc). This is probably what your professor wants you to do as this sounds like a typical problem to use when a student is first learning pointers and arrays. This is a great approach, just remember to call free on your memory when you are finished. The tricky part here is that you still have to know the size of the array you want ahead of time (not at compile time though of course).

Comment: "would not possibly be filled by the user input" until that one time in that one mission-critical high-security application... There are safe(r) functions and other solutions than hoping to gods the user doesn't surprise you.

Comment: @peachykeen. We are not talking about a mission-critical high-security application, we are talking about a homework problem. There are plenty of times programmers do this. I can't tell you how many times I have read: char buffer[1000]; memset(buffer, '\0', 1000);  in other (well-known) programs before taking user input before.

Comment: Of course you can and people have and it won't be run at NASA in this case, but there's *absolutely no reason whatsoever* to perpetuate the practice. Bad uses of it in real life have caused an entire class of bugs (buffer overruns), some of which have had real-world security implications.

Comment: Ignoring the part where he's dead, there's still no reason to teach bad practices (which abound in books, particularly ones like this which work in a limited scope). This is also one that really needs to go away, because ti can cause real problems.

Comment: @peachykeen, there is in fact a reason to give someone the option. They are learning C and they have not yet been introduced to pointers or dynamic memory allocation. In order to not confuse them at the moment, you present them with this option. I agree that, once in the field, this is never a good option.

Comment: Agreed, but with heavy stress that you never, ever do it in real life and immediately followed with a lesson in proper memory management. Even in that case, using a safer version of the function is a good idea.